# How to get dropbox files thumbnails in filelist?

Tags: php, api, laravel-4, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am integrating Dropbox into a Laravel/PHP project to allow subscribers to link their Dropbox account and access files from Dropbox storage.

I am able to fetch directories and files list from Dropbox and also there are API to download files or generate a thumbnail for images. But the issue is that generating a thumbnail for each image is a very slow process. So, I am looking for a solution to get thumbnail URL in file list as other services like google drive provide us.

Comment: Dropbox allows to fetch thumbnails for up to 25 files in one request - https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_thumbnail_batch

Comment: The `get_thumbnail_batch` endpoint mentioned above is the best solution currently. That still only returns the thumbnail data, not links, though. We'll consider this a feature request for a way to get thumbnail links.

Comment: Thanks, @Evil_skunk

Comment: @Greg, right its works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by using dropbox thumbnail batch request.

Here is the doc page:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_thumbnail_batch

Dropbox allow fetching 25 thumbnails in one request.